# Conservation of energy in a numerical simulation of a particle in magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, energy-conservation, computational-physics, simulations

I'm currently working on my physics project in Mathematica. My goal is to simulate a 3d trajectory of a charged particle, moving in constant magnetic field generated by a loop (with the electric current flow) and I have done most of my work.
I'm confident that code for calculating trajectories work properly (my teacher reviewed it) but then I need to eliminate not-real scenarios. In order to check is it real, my teacher advised me to check is the energy of particle conserved and then I met obstacles. I will try to show it on example.
Let's consider particle inside the loop with velocity $(v_x,v_y,0)$, it will only move in XY plane since Z component of velocity $= 0$ with very satysfying trajectory which looks like rosetta.
Then I look for function of kinetic energy:
$E_k=\frac{1}{2}m|v^2|=\frac{1}{2}m({v_x^2+v_y^2+v_z^2})$
There is my trajectory and graph of kinetic energy:
[image]
[image: Function of V^2[t]]

It looks a bit like a linear function. I'm not sure how to interpret but I know it's shaky since my project is based on numerical calculations (since most of trajectories can't be found analytically), but what is more important, it for sure is not constant. My first thought was that it is happening because part of the energy changed to potential energy, or there is a work made against the Lorentz's force. Before writing a post I of course made some research by myself and found that  both of these things can't happen (or maybe I wrongly understood it).
It is not a single-case scenario. All of my $E_k$ graphs don't show energy conservation, even in cases where I'm sure my trajectory is good. For example:
[image: Trajectory of particle moving toward loop]

[image: Kinetic energy in trajectory of partice moving toward loop]

Am I missing something? The goal of the project is to train our mathematica skills so model like this is above my math/physics knowledge. It isn't really that important since I'm using numerical calculations anyway. Maybe I wrongly understand my professor and energy isn't really conserved? In case you need it, I can show you separately graphs of $v_x,v_y,v_z$, my code or anything you need.

Comment: I should note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/168783) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/168783) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Comment: In spite of that, let me mention that energy in general might not be conserved in numerical computations. For example, if you try solving the harmonic oscillator numerically with [Euler's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method) (just to give a simple example), the energy won't be conserved due to the occurrence of numerical errors. **I am not sure if that's what's going on**, but it is something to keep in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the labelling of vertical axes on both graphs — all labels equal a constant value (3 and 4); so the perturbations of the speed on both graphs are probably negligible in their value and have emerged due to some approximations taken by Mathematica. You can also check it if you take $v_x$, $v_y$ and $v_z$ for some arbitrary moments of time and calculate $v=\sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2+v_z^2}$ — you should get approximately the same answer for $v$.